# All elements of an array cannot be accessed from a for loop in monthCalendar Control - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, monthcalendar

I have a bit of an issue here with the monthCalendar Control in Visual Basic. What is happening in the program is I have a calendar and a text box. The user selects a date on the calendar, then types in information into the textbox component, then presses the add button. From there the add button sets up a parallel array that contains the selected date and the added string from the text box as a way to add planner information for each date. Then the date is bolded for each time an addition like this has happened.

From there you are suppose to be able to click each bolded date and view the information you added. The issue is this only works on the last added date. For some reason it will only read the last element added to the array. I have the for loop down below. I do not understand why I cannot select any bolded date and view the text added. I have option strict on so I know no data loss is occurring. Also I know the date is being selected and placed into the string each time a date is selected on the calendar because I am displaying it onto a label each time. What is the problem. Is it some logical error I am not catching or is it something else?

```
Public Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged


    For index As Integer = 0 To intSizeOfSelectedDatesAry - 1
        strSelectedDay = CStr(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start) ' place the selected date into a string
        lblError.Text = strSelectedDay
        lblError.Visible = True
        Dim strAryDate As String = arySelectedDates(index)
        If (arySelectedDates(index) = strSelectedDay) Then
            lblInstructions.Text = strSelectedDay
            lblSelectedDate.Text = aryTextForDates(index)
            index = intSizeOfSelectedDatesAry - 1

        End If

    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: vba != vb.net. If you don't know what language you're using, you're going to have a really tough go of it friend.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it

Comment: Why does no one know any thing still?

Comment: Because you've not written a very good question. Please visit the [help] and browse through some highly upvoted questions in the Vb.net tag to get a feel for what a good question looks like. Once you've done that, come back and edit your Q to make it more clear and concise.

Comment: This is also relevant reading. http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/